# How can I get the maxium number of concurrent connections to MySQL over a specific time interval?

Tags: mysql, monitoring

I have a monitoring app that checks MySQL's [Threads_connected](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_connected)  and [Max_used_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Max_used_connections) variables every X seconds.

Neither of these variables tells me what I want to know: **The highest number of concurrent connections since the last check** (X seconds ago).

In the past, I've used `FLUSH STATUS` to reset Max_used_connections some time after the critical level is reached, but this method isn't ideal for a number of reasons, and [according to the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/flush.html):

> This is something you should use only when debugging a query.

Before I head down the path of a complicated analysis of the [query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html), is there anything I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is finding some what (maybe through a cron job) to record the 'Threads_connected' values every minute, and then calculate the max of these values.

I'm not sure if you can do exactly what you are asking for without resetting the 'Max_used_connections' before your monitoring period.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dave. I am tracking Threads_connected every 5 minutes, and that does alert me to serious trouble. I just wish I could see that value over time... Running a cron on the target system is out of the question.